# Image being rotated when stored as bitmap in F#

Tags: image-processing, io, f#

I am using F# for some image processing related activities.

If I get the images using

```
let imagesForRecognition = 
    Directory.GetFiles("/RImages/","*.jpg")
    |> Array.map(fun x -> new Bitmap(x))
```

And then do this.

```
    imagesForRecognition.[0].Save("A.jpg")
```

The image is rotated 90 degrees, if my image is of size 1080x1920. I used some 528x960 and they were not rotated. I find this behavior strange.

I am using Xamarin Studio Mac OS X

Comment: Probably `Bitmap` does not preserve Exif data.

Comment: Your question has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in `Xamarin.Forms`. 
However as I use `XLabs`, when my app takes picture I have access to `MediaFile` object. This class has one interesting property `Orientation`. I can check this property and perform some code to get the image in proper format as I want.

```
let prepare (orientation:ExifOrientation) img =
    match orientation with
    | ExifOrientation.BottomRight -> rotate 180 img
    | ExifOrientation.TopLeft -> img
    | _ -> img
```

This is something suitable for my needs, because I've never seen that smartphones I had, used other `ExifOrientation` than `BottomRight` or `TopLeft`